R/ggplot2 combines styling of two seperate layers
I wrote a script visualising ECMWF forecasting data on a hillshade map of Denmark. As long as I do not include the forecasting data on the map, everything looks as expected, but when I include the data layer, it combines the styling of the layers and do not put the forecasting data on top of the hillshade map. Anyone knows why? Could it be, that it can be related to the both scale fills? If so, how can I get around that?
Here is the script:
# Load required libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(elevatr)
library(terra)
library(stars)
library(dplyr)

# Read the GRIB2 file
grib_data <- read_stars("tp.grib2")
# NOTE: Be aware to regrid ECMWF forecast data before you can use it here with:
# $ grib_set -r -w packingType=grid_ccsds -s packingType=grid_simple input.grib2 output.grib2

# Convert to a data frame
tp <- as.data.frame(grib_data, xy = TRUE)

# Convert unit from m to mm
tp[4] <- tp[3] * 100

# Rename columns for clarity
names(tp)[3] <- "tp"
names(tp)[4] <- "tp_mm"

# Set 0 to NA
tp[4][tp[4] < 1] <- NA

# Define the custom color palette
tp_colors <- c("#DAEEE5", "#A8EDCC", "#82D3A3", "#54AFA7", "#3373A8", "#460DA3", "#A822BA")
tp_levels <- c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 300)

# Create a custom color scale function
scale_fill_tp <- function() {
  scale_fill_stepsn(colors = tp_colors, 
                    values = scales::rescale(tp_levels),
                    limits = range(tp_levels),
                    breaks = tp_levels,
                    na.value = NA,
                    labels = paste0(tp_levels, " mm")
                    )
}

# Get Denmark map data
denmark <- ne_countries(country = "denmark", scale = "large", returnclass = "sf")

# Get administrative boundaries of Denmark
admin_boundaries <- ne_states(country = "denmark", returnclass = "sf")

# Get elevation data for Denmark using elevatr
elevation <- get_elev_raster(denmark, z = 7, clip = "bbox")

# Convert elevation to terra raster
elevation_terra <- rast(elevation)

# Calculate slope and aspect
slope <- terrain(elevation_terra, "slope", unit = "radians")
aspect <- terrain(elevation_terra, "aspect", unit = "radians")

# Generate hillshade
hillshade <- shade(slope, aspect, angle = 45, direction = 315)

# Mask hillshade values below 0.7
hillshade[hillshade < 0.7] <- NA

# Convert the Denmark shape to a SpatVector for masking
denmark_vect <- vect(st_as_sf(denmark))

# Mask the hillshade using the Denmark shape
masked_hillshade <- mask(hillshade, denmark_vect)

# Convert masked hillshade to data frame for plotting
masked_hillshade_df <- as.data.frame(masked_hillshade, xy = TRUE)

# Create a data frame for cities in Denmark
cities <- data.frame(
  name = c("Copenhagen", "Aarhus", "Odense", "Aalborg", "Esbjerg", "Kolding", "Sønderborg"),
  longitude = c(12.5683, 10.2035, 10.4024, 9.9217, 8.4594, 9.4738, 9.7856),
  latitude = c(55.6761, 56.1629, 55.4038, 57.0489, 55.4808, 55.4914, 54.9116)
)

# Create the map with masked hillshade
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = denmark, fill = NA, color = alpha("#A2A2A2", 0.1), lwd = 4) + # Shadow
  geom_sf(data = denmark, fill = NA, color = alpha("#A2A2A2", 0.3), lwd = 2) + # Shadow
  geom_sf(data = denmark, fill = "#FFF7DB") +
  geom_raster(data = masked_hillshade_df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = hillshade), alpha = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#FFF7DB", high = "black", guide = "none") +
  geom_sf(data = admin_boundaries, fill = NA, color = "#A2A2A2", lwd = 0.3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(8, 13), ylim = c(54.6, 57.8)) +
  
  geom_raster(data = tp, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = tp_mm), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_tp() +

  geom_point(data = cities, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color = "black", size = 2, shape = 1) + # Points for cities
  geom_point(data = cities, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color = "black", size = 1, shape = 20) + # Points for cities
  
  # Adjusted label for Copenhagen separately
  geom_text(data = cities, 
            aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, label = name), 
            vjust = -1, hjust= 0.5,
            color="black") +
  
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0, size=18),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0, size=14),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.margin = margin(20, 20, 20, 20, "pt"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#F9F9F9", color = "#FFFFFF"),
    text=element_text(family="Futura"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#F9F9F9", color = "#FFFFFF"),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.box = "horizontal",
    legend.box.just = "center",
    legend.key.width = unit(3, 'cm'),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    # aspect.ratio = 1, # Figure as square
  ) +
  labs(
    x = NULL, 
    y = NULL, 
    title = "Total precipitation in 24 hours for Denmark", 
    subtitle = "Forecast for 2024-12-08", 
    caption = "Visualisation: niklasjordan.com, geofare.dk; Data: ECMWF, NaturalEarth, Elevatr"
  )

ggsave(
  "filename.png",
  plot = last_plot(),
  device = "png",
  dpi = "retina",
  bg = NULL,
)


Well, in vanilla ggplot2 you can't have two different scales for the same aesthetic and you should get a warning about that, i.e. the second scale_fill overrides the first. Instead have a look at the ggnewscale package which was made for this use case.

Thanks @stefan that works. Thanks a lot!
